# Get camera focal length OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I can obtain focal length using the camera parameters in Android like this:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Log.d(TAG, "Focal length:"+parameters.getFocalLength());
```

It gives me 3.97 (correct). Since I use OpenCV for my project, I want to use the variable already provided, which is:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Focal length:"+Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FOCAL_LENGTH);
```

But it gives me a result of 8005. I'm new to OpenCV, so if anyone could give me a hint, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I believe it's has something to do with the units. and quick Google on it suggests openCV works in world coordinates, so the 8005 is an distance in terms of pixels. To covert from one to the other young need to figure out the conversion rate, I think there's a calibration function for this.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Then I'll look into camera calibration first. Will update the post later.

Comment: @will: I just calibrated the camera as shown in this link, http://se.cs.ait.ac.th/cvwiki/opencv:tutorial:camera_calibration, and got different values compared to the one using Highgui. fx= 3.81674438e+003 and fy = 3.90492334e+003 (in pixel coordinates, I supposed). Why is that? Excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: how different are you values? I have never actually done anything like this before, just read about it before posting that comment. But you shouldsshould bare in mind that this is a calibration, each camera is going to be different. If they weren't all different, there wouldn't be any need for this calibration.

Comment: and yeah I don't know why it's different from highgui, sorry.

Comment: Never mind. Got the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you use from Highgui is Constant. It is the same whatever the camera is. I think you to stick to the android camera parameter

Comment: Ah, thanks! My brain was out for a holiday, it takes me two days to understand your answer. lol.